# RUNIT - created first service directory, "sv start testrun" does not work

Tags: runit

I'm pretty new to runit. I installed it on a Ubuntu host.

What I did:

1) created a dir `testrun` in `/etc/sv`

2) created a script `run` in `/etc/sv/testrun/run`, the script content:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec /root/FP/annotate-output python /root/FP/test.py | logger -t svtest
```

3) If I call directly /etc/sv/testrun/run it executes successfully

4) I run `sv start testrun` (or `sv run testrun`, `sv restart testrun`), all of them end up with the same error msg:

```
fail: sv: unable to change to service directory: file does not exist
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I'm new to runit and base all my actions on the information found here:
http://smarden.org/runit/

Comment: Not worth an answer but I arrived here with the same error. I had changed the container image from mysql to mariadb and startup scripts were still trying to restart mysql, when the new binary was mariadb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `sv` controls services that are started and monitored by `runit` (using `runsv`). As runit on my machine does not actually replace `sysvinit`, it does not run and does not monitor the `/services/` which should contain symbolic links to `/etc/sv/` directories.

Running `runsv /etc/sv/testrun/` seems to do the expected runit behavior.

Comment: This is the wrong answer, but I don't downvote out of principle.

Answer (score 6):

Your service isn't set up correctly.  The reason it worked is that you invoked it directly from the service *definition* and not from the actual service *control*.

When runit's service management starts, it expects a `/service` directory to exist, although some installs (like Debian Jessie) currently have it at `/etc/service` for reasons unknown.  The error message comes from this missing directory, which it is trying to change to, hence the `unable to change service directory` message.  Do the following as root:

```
mkdir -p /etc/service
cd /
ln -s /etc/service
cd /service
ln -s /etc/sv/testrun
```

This will:

- create the service directory if it doesn't exist
- place a symlink in the root so that runsvdir will be able to change to `/service` as its working directory
- creates a link to your `testrun` service, assuming you have it defined at `/etc/sv/testrun`

`runsvdir` will then be able to change its directory into `/service`, find your symlink for `testrun`, and then launch it.  You can verify this by using `ps fax` or `pstree -A` to see the process tree; there should be a `runsv` with your command attached to it.  *Note: sometimes it may take a second or two for the runsvdir process to get its head oriented, so if you look right away and don't see it in the process tree, wait 2-3 seconds and try again, and it should show up.  This appears to only happen when it starts up.*

Comment: A side note: if you look at the stage 2 script in Debian Jessie (2014-08-20 as of this writing), you'll see that it invokes runsvdir with /service instead of /etc/service.  If you don't like having the symlink for /service around in the root of the filesystem, simply change the stage 2 script to /etc/service and it will be "correct" on the next reboot.